# What is the best way to get the external IP of a machine in python?

Tags: python, networking, ip, ip-address

I'm playing around with some server side things in Python and I'd like the program to be able to be used outside of my LAN. What would be the best way about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off the top of my head you could use an external webpage that returns your ip.  For example using the page myip.dnsdynamic.org:

```
import urllib2
myip = urllib2.urlopen("http://myip.dnsdynamic.org/").read()
```